# CakePHP installation with multiple projects gives `require_once` error on composer

Tags: cakephp-2.0, runtime-error, composer-php, require-once

I am trying to run 2 cakephp installations on the same server. However, when I finished setting up the code and the apache vhost settings I ended up getting the following error:

```
Error: require_once(): Cannot redeclare class composerautoloaderinit922f66fe427c0b7305f553dc8d1952be    
File: /var/www/path/app/Vendor/autoload.php 
Line: 5
```

and similarly, on other installation I get:

```
Error: require_once(): Cannot redeclare class composerautoloaderinit922f66fe427c0b7305f553dc8d1952be    
File: /var/www/path_second/app/Vendor/autoload.php  
Line: 5
```

1. I thought of replacing `require_once` with just `require`, but I can't figure out how many includes there will be and what that will do to performance.
2. I thought of removing one of the folders since apparently its being loaded, but then neither of the two projects I want breaking because at some point for some reason that does not get loaded. Those two projects should be independent.
3. I wonder if composer should be there at all?!

What should I do?

Comment: I think there is more info needed. Did you do some symlink connection between the two installations? You should try to explain why these two installations do require each other.

Comment: I have not done anything special. I just have two separate folders in which I cloned two copies of the same project.

Comment: Is there an include path involved? Usually `require_once` will prevent including the same class twice, but this relies on the fact that this class is only contained in ONE file, and if the same class is inside TWO files, and the second file is also required, this filter will not work. Essentially, you have to check the code path all the way up to the error to see what code is included.

Comment: each of the two installations comes with its own set of files